# Tranform Pandas dataframe columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large `Pandas` dataframe of 2002 columns and 258 rows, where each column represents a product and each row presents the sales of each product on a given day.

I would like to transform this to a `Pandas` dataframe with 2002 * 258 = 516,516 rows and 2 columns containing the product name and the sales amount. How do I do this efficiently in `Python`?

The following data can serve as an example:

```
d = {'Product 1': [1, 2], 'Product 2': [3, 4], 'Product 3': [1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df)
           a  b
0  Product 1  1
1  Product 2  3
2  Product 3  1
3  Product 1  2
4  Product 2  4
5  Product 3  1
```

Alternative for better performance with [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) or [`numpy.repeat.html`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.tile(df.columns, len(df)), 'b':df.values.ravel()})
print (df)
           a  b
0  Product 1  1
1  Product 2  3
2  Product 3  1
3  Product 1  2
4  Product 2  4
5  Product 3  1
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.repeat(df.columns, len(df)), 'b':df.values.T.ravel()})
print (df)
           a  b
0  Product 1  1
1  Product 1  2
2  Product 2  3
3  Product 2  4
4  Product 3  1
5  Product 3  1
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(145)

#[258 rows x 2002 columns]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(258,2002))).add_prefix('Product ')
#print (df)


In [112]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'a':np.tile(df.columns, len(df)), 'b':df.values.ravel()})
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop

In [113]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'a':np.repeat(df.columns, len(df)), 'b':df.values.T.ravel()})
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop

In [114]: %timeit df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index', var_name='product', value_name='sales')
100 loops, best of 3: 18 ms per loop

In [115]: %timeit df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit df.unstack().swaplevel().sort_index()
10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'Product 1': [1, 2], 'Product 2': [3, 4], 'Product 3': [1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=pd.date_range('2015-01-04', periods=2))
print (df)
            Product 1  Product 2  Product 3
2015-01-04          1          3          1
2015-01-05          2          4          1

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.repeat(df.columns, len(df)), 
                   'b': np.tile(df.index, len(df.columns)),
                   'c': df.values.T.ravel()})
print (df)

           a          b  c
0  Product 1 2015-01-04  1
1  Product 1 2015-01-05  2
2  Product 2 2015-01-04  3
3  Product 2 2015-01-05  4
4  Product 3 2015-01-04  1
5  Product 3 2015-01-05  1
```

Comment: I like that the speed of your 3rd method, but is there a way to extend it to include a first column containing the dates?

Comment: Give me some time

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly it.

Comment: Note that `df.unstack().swaplevel().sort_index()` sorts by the first index at the end (which I assumed was necessary). Running just `df.unstack().swaplevel()` to get the equivalent result seems to be actually fastest...

Comment: @jdehesa - OP need the fastest solution, so I only simply timings all solutions. But in my opinion OP need DataFrame, so you need `reset_index`. But because need the fastest solution, not sure if `numpy` is possible beat here with some pandas solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
df = df.unstack().swaplevel().sort_index()
print(df)

0  Product 1    1
   Product 2    3
   Product 3    1
1  Product 1    2
   Product 2    4
   Product 3    1
```

Or if you do not need to sort by the first index:

```
df = df.unstack().swaplevel()
print(df)

0  Product 1    1
1  Product 1    2
0  Product 2    3
1  Product 2    4
0  Product 3    1
1  Product 3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index', var_name='product', value_name='sales')
```

Will give you:

```
   index    product  sales
0      0  Product 1      1
1      1  Product 1      2
2      0  Product 2      3
3      1  Product 2      4
4      0  Product 3      1
5      1  Product 3      1
```

Where `index` here is effectively the day indicator (rename as appropriate if necessary).

Comment: I that the solution produces the index column, but in my real example this doesn't work probably it is in datetime format. Any idea how to make it work with datetime?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. I just needed to substitute 'index' with 'date', which is the name of the index column in my dataframe.